# Visual Studio 2013 ultimate with update 4 setup failed

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I have installed this version on my Windows 8.1.

Because of some problems I re-installed Windows again.

Now I'm stuck on installation page.

I got this error:

[image]

I also downloaded and installed  `build tools 2013 full` from Microsoft.

But nothing changes!

I searched on the Internet and can't see the same problem.

I did whatever I could, from installing this component manually to reading logs and clearing data cache!

Any idea?

**Update :** i attached the log file,if any one could see the problem there .
[the log file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ebhvyocrduiv35/dd_vs_ultimate_20150523170555.log?dl=0)

Comment: This is just a guess, but maybe your Package Cache (located in the Program Files dir I think) is missing the setup files for the mentioned component. I've read a Microsoft KB which said, that this could cause issues, if a setup can't locate the required dir inside the cache. I'll post it,  when I find it.

Comment: check the answer to this question, it contains two links, that might be helpful to you. http://superuser.com/questions/455853/can-i-delete-the-the-folder-c-programdata-package-cache

Comment: it also happened before deleting the cache data ! i think it has another problem,but i don't know where it is !!

Comment: have you looked up the events log? It should an entry telling you what component is missing. According to the link it should be on the Warning level and contain the word "MsiInstaller"

Comment: @wodzu i attached log file,i couldn find any thing special in it .

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look at line 3307, it says:

> Validate custom path failed: Length greater then 260: H:\Program Backup\Visual Studio\Microsoft Visual Studio 2013\Microsoft.Visual.Studio.Ultimate.2013.with.Update.4_p30download.com\Microsoft.Visual.Studio.Ultimate.2013.with.Update.4_p30download.com\packages\BuildTools_MSBuildResMsi_x86\BuildTools_MSBuildResMsi.msi

and then in line 3309:

> WARNING: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Obviously the path is too long. You should try to move the location of your Visual Studio installer to a higher directory or shorten some names.